# Java: Parsing a WSDL to an Interface

Tags: java, wsdl

The project I'm working on requires me to recieve a WSDL, parse it, and spit out an appropriate Interface. How should I go about doing it? I'm assuming it would be possible to read the WSDL file, get the appropriate information, and then write that programmatically to a .java file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) to generate your classes.